# Speeding up groupby().apply() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a large dataset containing records of events attended by different individuals on certain dates. I'm trying to aggregate this by ID and Year and return a new summarised dataframe.

```
d = pd.DataFrame([["1", 2013, "a"]
    , ["1", 2014, "a"]
    , ["1", 2015, "b"]
    , ["1", 2017, "c"]
    , ["1", 2018, "c"]
    , ["2", 2013, "b"]
    , ["2", 2014, "a"]
    , ["2", 2015, "a"]
    , ["2", 2017, "b"]
    , ["2", 2018, "b"]]
    , columns = ["ID","Year","Event"])

  ID  Year Event
0  1  2013     a
1  1  2014     a
2  1  2015     b
3  1  2017     c
4  1  2018     c
5  2  2013     b
6  2  2014     a
7  2  2015     a
8  2  2017     b
9  2  2018     b
```

I'd like to aggregate different measures over a fixed time window, returning a cumulative count of events that took place before the year, and in-year features.

```
  ID  Year total_a total_b total_c a_this_year b_this_year c_this_year
0  1  2016       2       1       0           0           0           0
1  1  2017       2       1       1           0           0           1
2  1  2018       2       1       2           0           0           1
3  2  2016       2       1       0           0           0           0
4  2  2017       2       2       0           0           1           0
5  2  2018       2       3       0           0           1           0
```

I have written the following to do this

```
def get_agg(df):

    out = {
        "Year" : []
        , "total_a" : []
        , "total_b" : []
        , "total_c" : []
        , "a_this_year" : []
        , "b_this_year" : []
        , "c_this_year" : []
    }
    
    for yr in range(2016,2019):
        
        df_filt = df[df["Year"] <= yr]
        
        out["YearId"].append(yr)
        for event in ["a", "b", "c":
            out["total_"+event].append(df_filt[df_filt.Event == event].Year.nunique()) 
            out[event+"_this_year].append(any(df_filt[df_filt.Event == event].Year == yr)) 
        
    return(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out))

d.groupby(ID).apply(get_agg)
```

However I'm finding huge performance issues on my full dataset (350k rows, 150k IDs). I am looking for ways to help optimise this process.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do it using pandas methods, e.g. although I am not sure if it exactly the desired output?

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame([["1", 2013, "a"]
    , ["1", 2014, "a"]
    , ["1", 2015, "b"]
    , ["1", 2017, "c"]
    , ["1", 2018, "c"]
    , ["2", 2013, "b"]
    , ["2", 2014, "a"]
    , ["2", 2015, "a"]
    , ["2", 2017, "b"]
    , ["2", 2018, "b"]]
    , columns = ["ID","Year","Event"])

# Add a dummy variable to count each event
d['Dummy'] = 1

# Aggregate observationns by event and year
d_agg = d.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Event'])['Dummy'].sum()
d_agg =  d_agg.reset_index()
d_agg['YearID'] = d_agg['Year'].astype(str) + "_" + d_agg['ID'].astype(str)
d_agg = d_agg.pivot(index='YearID', columns='Event', values='Dummy')
d_agg = d_agg.fillna(0)

# Get cumulative events for a rolling window
d_agg_cum = d_agg.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).sum()
d_agg_cum.columns = [col + "_total" for col in d_agg_cum.columns]
d_agg.columns = [col + "_this_year" for col in d_agg.columns]
d_agg = d_agg.merge(d_agg_cum, left_index=True, right_index=True)

# If you want the year and id columns back
d_agg['Year'] = d_agg.index.str.split("_").str[0]
d_agg['ID'] = d_agg.index.str.split("_").str[1]
d_agg = d_agg.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering data *twice* for any year/event combination (once for less or equal, once for equal) you may just populate your dictionary with the exact-year data.

Then is is trivial to update each year's cumulative data with the values from previous ones.

But with 350K rows perhaps all this, or at least the exact-year aggregation part, would be better done as an SQL job than a Python/Pandas one